# ¿Como puedo hallar el valor a pagar?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Como puedo hacer para que con el puesto encontrado pueda obtener toda la información del automotor al que nos referimos según su id o placa, para así poder saber cual el tipo (moto o carro) y el tiempo que se quedo, para poder calcular el valor a pagar.
Si les sirve les voy a adjuntar el problema, siento no haberme explicado bien, cualquier ayuda es bienvenida, estoy un poco perdido.

El departamento de planeación de una Universidad requiere de un sistema para administrar los 300
parqueaderos de la universidad (250 para carros y 50 para motos). Dicho sistema debe permitir registrar el
ingreso de un automotor al parqueadero de la U (si hay puestos de parqueo disponibles), indicando la hora de
ingreso, el tipo de vehículo (moto o carro), la placa y el número de identificación de quien maneja el vehículo.
Igualmente, el sistema debe permitir dar salida a un automotor, para lo cual el usuario debe indicar la placa o
identificación del conductor. El sistema debe mostrar el valor a pagar de acuerdo al número de horas (o
fracción) de uso del parqueadero con una tarifa de 500 hora para vehículos tipo moto y 1000 para vehículos
tipo carro. En caso de que el tiempo de permanencia en el parqueadero sea superior a 4 horas, se cobrará
una tarifa plena de 2500 para motos y 5000 para carros.
 El sistema deberá permitir saber cuántos puestos de parqueo están desocupados tanto de carro como de
moto. Igualmente, deberá mostrar el dinero que se ha recaudado por parqueadero. Además, el sistema debe
generar un listado de los vehículos que permanecieron por más de 4 horas en el parqueadero. El listado debe
mostrar la placa de cada vehículo y el tiempo de permanencia en la Universidad.

```py
class Automotor:

    CARRO = 1
    MOTO = 2

    def __init__(self, hora_ingreso, placa, tipo, id_conductor):
        self.hora_ingreso = hora_ingreso
        self.placa = placa
        self.tipo = tipo
        self.id_conductor = id_conductor



    def calcular_valor_a_pagar(self,puesto_encontrado):
        pass

class Puesto:

    CARRO = 1
    MOTO = 2

    def __init__(self, tipo):
        self.tipo = tipo
        self.vehiculo = None

    def asignar_vehiculo(self, hora_ingreso, placa, tipo, id_conductor):
        self.vehiculo = Automotor(hora_ingreso, placa, tipo, id_conductor)

    def desocupar_puesto(self):
        pass


class Parqueadero:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dinero_recaudo = 0
        self.puestos = []
        for i in range(0, 250):
            self.puestos.append(Puesto(Puesto.CARRO))

        for i in range(0, 50):
            self.puestos.append(Puesto(Puesto.MOTO))


    def registrar_ingreso_vehiculo(self, hora_ingreso, placa, tipo, id_conductor):
        puesto_registrado = self.verificar_puesto_disponible(tipo)
        if puesto_registrado != None:
            puesto_registrado.asignar_vehiculo(hora_ingreso, placa, tipo, id_conductor)
        else:
            return False

    def verificar_puesto_disponible(self, tipo):
        for puesto in self.puestos:
            if puesto.vehiculo == None and puesto.tipo == tipo:
                return puesto
        return None

    def dar_salida_a_automotor(self, **placa_identificacion):
        if "placa" in placa_identificacion:
            id_vehiculo = placa_identificacion["placa"]
        elif "identificacion" in placa_identificacion:
            id_vehiculo = placa_identificacion["identificacion"]
        else:
            return False
        puesto_encontrado = self.buscar_automotor(id_vehiculo)


    def buscar_automotor(self, id_vehiculo):
        for puesto in self.puestos:
            if puesto.vehiculo != None and id_vehiculo == puesto.vehiculo.placa or id_vehiculo == puesto.vehiculo.id_conductor:
                return puesto
        return None

    def acumular_dinero(self):

        pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo no habría usado una lista para los puestos, sino un diccionario (dos en realidad, uno para autos y otro para motos). No es necesaria la clase `Puesto`

En ese diccionario, las claves serían el id del vehículo (que puede ser tanto su placa como el id del conductor, sin necesidad de hacer distinción entre ambas), y los valores serían objetos de tipo Automotor. Por tanto este diccionario guarda sólo qué puestos están ocupados y qué vehículos los ocupan. Para saber cuántos hay libres basta restar de 250 (o 50) la longitud del diccionario correspondiente.

Cuando un usuario llega, si hay hueco para él, se crea un Automotor con los parámetros apropiados, y se guarda en ese diccionario, asignándolo a la clave correspondiente.

Cuando se va a ir, entrando al diccionario por la clave del id de vehículo, extraes el Automotor y puedes calcular el coste asociado. A la vez, si ves que ha permanecido más de 4h, puedes guardar ese Automotor en otra lista, para la estadística final que te pide de vehiculos que hayan permanecido más de 4h.

Básicamente este diccionario te evita tener que iterar por listas para contar huecos libres, huecos ocupados o buscar ids de vehículos.

No está claro qué ocurre al final del día. Se presupone que antes del fin del día todo vehículo que había entrado, habrá salido de nuevo en algún momento.  De no ser así no está claro cómo contar los vehículos que quedaron dentro, de cara a esta estadística, o si deben quedar "guardados" de alguna forma para el día siguiente. Lo más sencillo sería suponer que no, y por si acaso "forzar" un desalojo artificial al final del día.

### Cálculo de tiempos

En cuanto a la pregunta que da título, para calcular el valor a pagar debería estar más claro en qué formato almacenas `hora_de_ingreso`, y obviamente necesitarás también una `hora_de_salida` que pasar como parámetro a la función que desocupa el puesto. Hay que restar ambas para saber el tiempo transcurrido, y lo más sencillo quizás sería que estos parámetros fueran del tipo `datetime.datetime`, pues Python sabe cómo restarlos dándote el resultado en segundos. Dividiendo por 3600, redondeando hacia arriba, sacas las horas o fracción. Por ejemplo:

```
ingreso = datetime.datetime.strptime("14:10", "%H:%M")
salida = datetime.datetime.strptime("15:20", "%H:%M")
t = salida-ingreso
horas = t.seconds//3600 + 1
```

En este ejemplo el resultado sería `horas=2`. El operador `//` hace la división entera en Python3.